# PHP Include, using document root path code - but I'm stuck-

Tags: php

I'm trying to use php includes for my Menu Navigation for my site, but some of the pages now reside inside folders - and I'm having the typical problem of bad links when pages are navigating from inside the various folders.

I thought I needed to create "the path" for my php includes, So I researched and found these nice/simple pieces of code below from a "how to article", it just didn't give me enough info to figure it out how to use it.

(I have used php includes for pages that all reside at the same root level just fine, it's the pages inside folders that I'm lost on.)

Please - if anyone could enlighten me...neither option below is responding as it is shown below - Am I supposed to insert the word 'localhost' in place of the 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ? Or 'index.php'? Or what am I missing? I have tried each of them between the body tags on the page needing the include. (my navigation.php is inside my includes folder.)

```
option1:

<?php 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/includes/navigation.php";
include_once($path);
?>

-- OR-- option2:

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/navigation.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Is /includes/ in the DOCUMENT_ROOT directory? If it is then either of your solutions should work. Note that the DOCUMENT ROOT value does not change in subdirectories, so should work for all files.

Comment: GOOD QUESTION- the includes folder is in the root directory of this site, but I think I just realized my problem-- I have several sites in my computers root directory (on the mamp server), so I think I needed to add the "elephant_mamp" folder to my path. I had been limiting my thinking site specific path - instead of server specific path.

Comment: So this is what I just used to make the code in my original question work ---  <?php 
  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  $path .= "/elephant_mamp/includes/navigation.php";
  include_once($path);
?>    Thanks @vogomatix for all the input, to help me figure out my limited thinking.

Answer (score 0):

PHP picks include files up from the path supplied, or from directories specified in the include path. Read [the manual for more info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Your use of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will work if the includes directory is a subfolder of the directory containing your website. However I will add that it is not good practise to put a PHP include directory into your DOCUMENT_ROOT directory, or at least I do not recommend doing so unless you have considered security issues, as it may inadvertently expose such things as database passwords etc.

A quick solution to your problem is to put the path to your includes directory in a $include_path variable and use that

e.g.

```
// don't forget trailing directory separator :-)
$include_path = '/Put/the/full/path/here/'; 
include( $include_path . 'navigation.php' ); // also works for include_once, require etc
```

Comment: But, when I publish the site, will I have to go back in and "edit each of my pages using this include code -- to change the path" -- to match the real server (instead of my personal computers path?)

Comment: This is what I used... <?php     $include_path =    '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/elephant_mamp/includes/';
    include( $include_path . 'navigation.php'); ?>

Comment: Not really sure where the elephant_mamp directory comes in, but I would guess that DOCUMENT_ROOT is the htdocs directory in that, so you could have `$include_path =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/elephant_mamp/includes'`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<?php include($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/includes/navigation.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Incorrect: HTTP_HOST is the URL and not a file path

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you are passing url not the file path.

You need to pass file path like C:\www\something\filename